# Drawing a portion of a hemisphere airspace

Tags: 3d, worldwind

I am trying to use WorldWind's SphereAirspace to construct a particular 3D airspace. The 3D shape I am trying to construct is a hemisphere cut parallel to the ground at two places, suppose at height h1 and h2 from the ground. The base of hemisphere is parallel to the ground. 
Found I don't have enough reputation to post an image, you can see the image here:
http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?45274-Drawing-a-portion-of-a-hemisphere-airspace

Thought of two solutions: 1.) Get intersection space of a hemisphere and a cuboid: Couldn't find any api for this. 2.) alter the drawing of the hemisphere.: trying to do this

I override the three functions in WorldWind's SphereAirspace drawSphere(), drawUnitSphere() and makeSphere() and tried to modify the drawing to get the cut portion. I am unable to understand the drawing pattern and the parameters that would affect the drawing to give a subset of the whole hemisphere,the way i need.

A direct help or any pointers in terms of the apis used in these functions, where I can study the drawing of this sphere would be helpful.

You can refer the SphereAirspace code here: http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/...eAirspace.java![enter image description here][1]