# Clipping a sphere

Tags: opengl, 3d

Had asked a question here:
[Drawing a portion of a hemisphere airspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768277/drawing-a-portion-of-a-hemisphere-airspace)

Probably it was more into GIS so have moved to more basic and specific implementation in OpenGL to get the desired output.

I have simply overridden/copied functions that are drawing the hemisphere and altering the GL part to basically INSERT clipping. I am able to draw the hemisphere centred at a location (latitude,longitude) and radius may be 2000. But when i cut it using a plane nothing happens. Please check the equation of the plane(its a plane parallel to the surface of the globe at height may be 1000, so (0,0,+1,1000))

The base class has drawUnitSphere so that might be causing some problems so trying to use GL's gluSphere(). But can't even see the sphere on globe. Used translate to shift it to my location(lat/lon) but still can't see it. Might be some issues with lat/lon and cartesian coordinates, or placing of my clipping code. Please check.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void drawSphere(DrawContext dc)
{
    double[] altitudes = this.getAltitudes(dc.getVerticalExaggeration());
    boolean[] terrainConformant = this.isTerrainConforming();
    int subdivisions = this.getSubdivisions();

    if (this.isEnableLevelOfDetail())
    {
        DetailLevel level = this.computeDetailLevel(dc);

        Object o = level.getValue(SUBDIVISIONS);
        if (o != null && o instanceof Integer)
            subdivisions = (Integer) o;            
    }

    Vec4 centerPoint = this.computePointFromPosition(dc,
        this.location.getLatitude(), this.location.getLongitude(), altitudes[0], terrainConformant[0]);

    Matrix modelview = dc.getView().getModelviewMatrix();
    modelview = modelview.multiply(Matrix.fromTranslation(centerPoint));
    modelview = modelview.multiply(Matrix.fromScale(this.getRadius()));
    double[] matrixArray = new double[16];
    modelview.toArray(matrixArray, 0, false);

    this.setExpiryTime(-1L); // Sphere geometry never expires.

    GL gl = dc.getGL(); // GL initialization checks for GL2 compatibility.
    gl.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_POLYGON_BIT | GL.GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
    try
    {

        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL.GL_CCW);

        // Were applying a scale transform on the modelview matrix, so the normal vectors must be re-normalized
        // before lighting is computed. In this case we're scaling by a constant factor, so GL_RESCALE_NORMAL
        // is sufficient and potentially less expensive than GL_NORMALIZE (or computing unique normal vectors
        // for each value of radius). GL_RESCALE_NORMAL was introduced in OpenGL version 1.2.
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        //clipping
        DoubleBuffer eqn1 = BufferUtils.createDoubleBuffer(8).put(new double[] {0, 0, 1, 100});
        eqn1.flip();
        gl.glClipPlane(GL.GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqn1);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
        try
        {
            gl.glLoadMatrixd(matrixArray, 0);
            //this.drawUnitSphere(dc, subdivisions);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(75.2f, 32.5f, 0.0f);
            gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GLU glu = dc.getGLU();
            GLUquadric qd=glu.gluNewQuadric();
            glu.gluSphere(qd,3.0f,20,20);
        }
        finally
        {
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        gl.glPopAttrib();
    }
}

@Override
public void drawUnitSphere(DrawContext dc, int subdivisions)
{
    Object cacheKey = new Geometry.CacheKey(this.getClass(), "Sphere", subdivisions);
    Geometry geom = (Geometry) this.getGeometryCache().getObject(cacheKey);
    if (geom == null || this.isExpired(dc, geom))
    {
        if (geom == null)
            geom = new Geometry();
        this.makeSphere(1.0, subdivisions, geom);
        this.updateExpiryCriteria(dc, geom);
        this.getGeometryCache().add(cacheKey, geom);
    }

    this.getRenderer().drawGeometry(dc, geom);
}

@Override
public void makeSphere(double radius, int subdivisions, Geometry dest)
{
    GeometryBuilder gb = this.getGeometryBuilder();
    gb.setOrientation(GeometryBuilder.OUTSIDE);

    GeometryBuilder.IndexedTriangleArray ita = gb.tessellateSphere((float) radius, subdivisions);
    float[] normalArray = new float[3 * ita.getVertexCount()];
    gb.makeIndexedTriangleArrayNormals(ita, normalArray);

    dest.setElementData(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, ita.getIndexCount(), ita.getIndices());
    dest.setVertexData(ita.getVertexCount(), ita.getVertices());
    dest.setNormalData(ita.getVertexCount(), normalArray);
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite follow your coordinates and transformations. But one thing to keep in mind is that the clip plane gets transformed with the inverse of the current modelview matrix when it is specified with `glClipPlane()`. So you need to watch what your current modelview matrix is when you make that call.

Comment: @Reto Koradi: Thanks, didn't get notification for this so couldn't respond. I am still stuck at the clipping part. I can see the sphere but clipping doesn't happen. You mention that "clip plane gets transformed with the inverse of the current modelview matrix" what does that mean? I have made some progress and asked a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098142/equation-of-a-plane-at-an-altitude-h-from-earths-surface?s=3|2.5863, you can check my latest code and respond there